# Computing GPS points accuracy

Tags: python, gps, utm, accuracy

I have stand alone GPS points and RTK points collected at the same time and I want to compute the accuracy (1 sigma) of the GPS points. Using the haversine formula, I computed the distance between the GPS points and corresponding RTK points

```
De = harv(lat_rtk, log_rtk, Lat_gps, Log_gps)
```

then I calculated the standard deviation of

```
sigma_De = std(De)
```

I'm using the Python.

How to find the `Sigma_north` and `Sigma_east`. The mean of error is not zero should the mean of error added to `sigma_DE` to get the true accuracy.

I tried to use mathematics format notation `$x$` but it did not work.